# Switch Statement based on if variables in two tables match

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a switch statement that I want to display one form or another based on if the id from one  table has the matching foreign key in another table.

So far what I have tried is nesting one while statement into another which isn't working.

```
$subresult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag");
$subresult2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tag_subscribe WHERE uid = $uid");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($subresult)) {
    $tid = $row['tid'];

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($subresult2)) {
        $tid2 = $row2['tid'];
    }
    if ($tid2 == $tid) {
        $subbedup = 'yes';
    } else {
        $subbedup = 'no';
    }

    switch ($subbedup) {
    case ('yes'):
        echo "alternate html form goes here because $tid2 == $tid";
        break;
    case ('no'):
        echo "html form goes here";
        break;
    }
}
```

So when this code is run, it only returns switch "no" except it will return one switch "yes" which just happens to be the last record of the second table that contains the foreign key.  When I think about it, that makes sense as it will just keep running through this loop until it runs out of records in the table.  So I spent about six minutes getting to this point and I have spent the last 6 hours trying to get it to work correctly without any luck.

So once again, fine people at SO, save me!  Please and Thank you :)

So my question is: How would this be done correctly?

Comment: i don't see why you have the while loop(s), and not do the compare in the db query

Comment: If I did the compare in the query it would only return what compared in the query.  I want to return everything if it compares or doesn't but if the compare is true display something different than if the compare is false.

Comment: kind of lost on this one, best of luck :-)

Comment: what I am creating is an html table and in each <td> is a submit button with a tag in it.  If the switch is 'yes' it means the tag is subscibed to and the form action goes to unsubcribe, 'no' means they are not subscribed and the action goes to subscribe.  mysql Table one is the tag table and mysql table two is the subscribe to tag table with the tag table id in it.

Comment: So basically what I am trying to do is list every tag in a submit button in an html table but change the form action of the submit button based on if the user is subscribed to the tag or not.

Comment: then a single querry with a join should return all the data you need to do it in one loop

Comment: What are your two queries: `$subresult` and `$subresult2`?

Comment: So you are suggesting to use a JOIN but then how could I set the switch?

Comment: edited to add in $subresult and $subresult2 code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of your database structure, so I'll improvise.

Given these sample tables and columns:

```
tags
id name

tag_subscriptions
user_id tag_id
```

The query below will loop through all tags. Each tag includes a `subscribed` column set to either "yes" or "no", depending on whether the current user is subscribed to that particular tag.

```
$sql="SELECT t.`id`, t.`name`, IF (ISNULL(ts.`tag_id`),'no','yes') AS `subscribed`
  FROM `tags` t
  LEFT JOIN `tag_subscriptions` ts ON (ts.`user_id`=$uid AND ts.`tag_id`=t.`id`)
  WHERE 1;"
```

Then loop through all tags:

```
$q=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    switch ($row['subscribed']) {
      case 'yes'
        // user is subscribed to this tag
        break;
      default:
        // user is not subscribed to this tag
    }
}
```

I think (hope) this is closer to what you're looking for.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58684/1/0

Comment: So this would display everything in the Tag table and switch when it comes to a record that matches in the subscribe tag table?   Sorry to ask a probably obvious question but that syntax is completely new to me as a php mysql noob.

Comment: Thanks.  I am digesting the info and will try to apply it soon.  I appreciate the help this seems like what I needed.

Comment: Well, I haven't been able to get this to work.  Not your fault though, it's obviously mine as I just can't wrap my head around this at the moment.  I think I'm just gonna shelf this part of my script for a bit until I get better acquainted with PHP and mysql and just run with an diffrent, less user friendly script made before that just splits the data into two html tables rather than try to put it all into one. Thanks a million @showdev, I'm gonna mark your answer as correct as I am sure it is, I just don't have the knowledge currently to make it play nice with my script.  Thanks again!

Comment: You may already have it sorted out, but I thought I'd revise my answer. My original one was flawed.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for using PDO as thats what i know, you can convert the idea to MYSQLi im sure.

```
$db = new PDO($hostname,$username,$password);

$arraySubTags = array();

$query = "SELECT tagID FROM tag_subscribe WHERE uid = :uid";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
$statement->execute();
$subscribedTags = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //or loop with a while using fetch()
$statement->closeCursor();

foreach($subscribedTags as $sTag)
{
    array_push($arraySubTags,$sTag);
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM tags GROUP BY tag";
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$allTags = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //or loop with a while using fetch()
$statement->closeCursor();

foreach($allTags as $tag)
{
    if(in_array($tag['tagID'], $arraySubTags))
    {
        echo "person is subscribed";
    }else{ echo "person not subscribed";}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dan.  I am not real familiar with PDO and I accept your apology :)  I appreciate you taking the time to write this out and teach me something new though.  Once I am more comfortable with PHP and MYSQL I plan on getting better acquainted with PDO.  I am writing a script to apply what I have learned so far then when that is done I plan on heavily editing it with some more advanced PHP that I learn after mastering the basics so I will be coming back to this I am sure when I re-write the script at a later date.  Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: This is pretty nice. Plus, you end up with sets of data for both "all tags" and "all subscriptions for current user", which could be useful later. Also +1 for PDO.

Answer (score 0):

This code just checks whether the last tag checked is subscribed to - to check for each one you need to move the switch statement into the outer while loop, after the if..else bit that sets the $subbedup variable for the current tag.

Or you could make $subbedup an array, indexed by the tag id, if you need to keep the switch separate for some reason.

Comment: it is set in the outer while loop isn't it?

Comment: Oh sorry, the indentation confused me there.

Comment: Maybe the if statement should be inside the inner while loop?

Comment: And it should break if there is a match, so that it doesn't carry on and possibly set it back to false.

Comment: thats ok, it confused me too when I went back to check when you mentioned it was somewhere where I thought it wasn't.  Thanks

Comment: "Maybe the if statement should be inside the inner while loop?"  worth a shot, I'll let you know it that works.   "nd it should break if there is a match, so that it doesn't carry on and possibly set it back to false"  I want it to carry on, some records will match and some won't and I want to display them all but differently based on if they match or not.